# Why is my Fortran module not making my index variable available?

Tags: module, fortran

This question is about Fortran. I need to pass an index `i` from the main program (i.e. do i = 1,30 ...) to a subroutine. I had created a module that gets the index, but somehow it is not available to the rest of the subroutines. In the program below I would like to use the `index` in the subroutine `vals4interp`, which I thought should be available since `index` is public. However it is not in fact available.

```
program main_prog  
 ...  
 do i = 1, timesteps   
     ...   
     call getindex(i)  
 enddo  
 end main_prog  


module myindex  
 !   
 implicit none  
public  
 integer,public ::index  
contains  
! get index of loop  
subroutine getindex(index)  
integer, intent(inout)::index   

 print*,'in getindex', index  
end subroutine getindex  
!  
 subroutine vals4interp(ti,this,tvar)   
...  
 ! Here I need 'index', but it's 0 !  

call getindex(ti) !! this doesn't help... dunno why I thought it would ... 

end vals4interp
```

Comment: Do you actually `use` your module in various parts of your program?

Comment: And do you have a `setindex` that sets the value of `index` somewhere?

Comment: Hi francescalus, the value of index is the value of the 'i' in the do loop. cheers (from previous duplicated question)

Comment: Hi, the value of index should be the value of 'i' in the do loop, and I just use once the module, in the main program to call the subroutine getindex. The print statement in the latter subroutine does have the value I need, I just can see that value in the subroutine vals4interp, where I actually use it. Cheers

Comment: I've already voted to close this question as a duplicate of OP's earlier version which itself is now deleted.  If I could I would vote to close it again on the grounds that there is insufficient information to properly diagnose the problem(s).  How can anyone debug a code with `...` all over the place ?  Post a question that complies with the advice given at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the routine `getindex()`, a variable `index` is used as a dummy argument. But this variable is actually a local variable in the subroutine and a different thing from the module variable `index`, although they have the same name.

```
subroutine getindex(index)  
    integer :: index    ! <--- this is a local variable different from the module variable "index"
    print*,'in getindex', index  
end subroutine getindex
```

More specifically, if the same variable name (here `index`) is used both for a module variable and a dummy argument, then the local variable takes precedence and "hides" the module variable; i.e., we cannot change the module variable `index` from inside the routine (*). To avoid this behavior, simply change the name of the dummy argument from `index` to anything different and make the module variable `index` visible (accessible) from inside the routine. For example,

```
subroutine getindex( idx )  
    integer, intent(in) :: idx   ! <--- a local variable
    print*,'in getindex', idx
    index = idx                  ! <--- set module variable "index"
end subroutine getindex
```

With this modification the subroutine `vals4interp` should print the expected value.

(*) As a related page, please see [Use variable from fortran subroutine argument list to set module variable of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040097/use-variable-from-fortran-subroutine-argument-list-to-set-module-variable-of-the)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is good advice to suggest to a beginner to modify variables not passed through a routine's argument list.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hmm, sorry, I can't catch your point... do you mean that it is better to import the module variable via the "use" statement and modify it directly?

Comment: In the second version of `getindex` in your answer the variable `index` is assigned to but is not passed to the routine through its argument list; the routine operates by side-effect.  And, as I wrote *I'm not sure ...*

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I see, yeah, it is certainly better and the code more clear to pass data via argument lists (and even better if the procedure has no side effects). Because the intent of OP's code seems to perform some interpolation of data along real-time evolution, it may be more clear to once save all the history (or trajectory) data in memory or disk, and then perform interpolation afterward (if possible).

Comment: Dear roygvib, thanks for your answer, it solved my problem. I'll try to be more careful with the treatment of dummy arguments. I tried to rename it once but I may had missed something then :( Cheers, Adriana